# web application with openstreetmap(OSM) in java

Tags: java, web-applications, dojo, gis, openstreetmap

I have a requirement of implementing maps i.e `GIS` in an existing java web application which i have developed using struts framework and has been developed in Eclipse Ganymede IDE.  I am completely new into GIS.

> Is it possible to implement Maps in java web applications. How do i do
>   it technically?

Does Dojo support it? Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Dojo has an out of the box solution, but we're currently working at a GIS web application using the [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) library and integration with Dojo using the `dojox/geo/openlayers` modules ([reference guide](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/geo/openlayers.html)).